# gnu assembler printf error

Tags: assembly, printf

My os is ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

---

I wasted many hours to fix it
really need your help

this test.s returns

```
Accessing a corrupted shared library






.code32

.section .data
par1:
.int 33
msg:
.asciz "%d\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl $par1
pushl $msg
call printf



cikis:
movl $1,%eax
movl $1,%ebx
int $0x80
```

ldd test.out

```
ldd test.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff615fe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbfb56f8000)
    /lib32/libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbfb5ae0000)
```

makefile

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc test.o -o test.out
```

// I also tried

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib32/ld-linux.so.2 -lc test.o -o test.out
```

How can I use C functions in gas on 64 bit ubuntu

Comment: Try adding `-melf_i386` to your `ld` command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change both how you assemble and link the program and how you're pushing `$par1` instead of `par1`:

```
.section .data
n:
.int 33
fmt:
.asciz "n: %d\n"
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
pushl n
pushl $fmt
call printf

movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Assemble and link with:

```
cc -nostdlib -Os -Wall -g3 -m32 -lc printf-x86.S -o printf-x86
```

**cc** here is just an alias for **gcc**. The regular compiler driver would know the right options to pass to **as** and **ld** plus it means your assembler source (.S) gets passed through the C preprocessor and you can use header files like `<sys/sdt.h>`.

Here's a GNU make fragment in case you need it:

```
%: %.S
        $(CC) -nostdlib $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
printf-x86: CFLAGS+=-m32
printf-x86: LDFLAGS+=-lc
```

Comment: returns /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
when I write

cc -nostdlib -Os -Wall -g3 -m32 -lc printf-x86.S -o printf-x86

Comment: @Assembler, install the i686 glibc development packages. You probably only have the x86-64 ones. The command is "yum install glibc-devel.i686" on Fedora, "apt-get install ia32-libs-dev" or "apt-get install libc6-dev:i386" on Ubuntu and Debian.